# Can a Canon 1100D produce high-quality pictures for a photo studio?

Tags: canon

I want to open a photo studio and I have a Canon 1100D/T3. I'm not sure whether it's good for that kind of business.

Comment: Your question is completely subjective and depends on what you want to photograph, what lenses you have and many many other factors. Its a question only you can answer. Photography isnt just the camera, its the person pushing the button....

Answer (score 5):

> I want to open a photo studio and I have a Canon D1100. I'm not sure whether it's good for that kind of business.

If you mean you want to open a commercial studio and charge money, I'd have to say you probably should not.

Your question is one a professional photographer should *never* need to ask someone else.

If you need to ask, you don't have even the minimal technical knowledge to do a decent job as a professional.

If your plan is to pick up the skills as you work, then I can guarantee you'll wind up in court being sued by probably more than one angry client.  Good pros get sued by angry clients, never mind people who don't know what they're doing.

Comment: Harsh, but true (:

Comment: A bit brutal but good advice

Comment: What Stephen failed to say is welcome  new user and fellow human to the site, Your camera is not considered to be a pro level camera. The rest is just ASSumptions about your skill and experience.

Comment: @alaska-man The camera is not the problem.  It may not be typical pro gear, but it's not a technical block to taking good shots.  The level of knowledge is, however, implicit in the question and that is a problem.  Who would be comfortable paying someone to take professional photos if they asked that question ?

Comment: @StephenG i did not dispute that, i merely pointed out that you are assuming to know the skill or experience of the the OP or anyone who would ask what YOU deem to be a stupid question,  and  your lack of tack, to put it nicely.  ALL kinds of people of all levels of experience come here to ask questions, we can at least treat them with respect and  answer them tactfully. I did not say your were wrong i just wanted point out that your bedside manner is not pleasant.

Comment: @Alas: Stephen's answer is a good one, and straight to the point.  +1 to him.  It is exactly what the OP needs to hear.  Sugar coating *"you are in way over your head, if you need to ask this you shouldn't be asking this"* wouldn't help anyone.  Also, everyone here is always judged by what they write.  The OP *did* show us enough about his level of photography knowledge for us to be confident that he shouldn't try to do it professionally at this point in his learning.  What would be rude would be not telling him that clearly and letting him crash and burn instead.  Get off your high horse.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what kind of photos one is producing in the studio.

Many types of studio work, such as product photography done for the purpose of making web sized images, are much more about lighting and correct positioning of both the in-frame subject(s) and the out-of-frame lights, light modifiers, and backdrops than they are about the camera and lens.

Other types of studio work, such as art reproduction, are very demanding of the camera and lens used to produce the images. Many of the other types of studio photography are somewhere in between.

As another answer has already expressed, the most concerning thing about the question is that it demonstrates a lack of awareness of whether a specific piece of equipment, not to mention their own skill level, is up to the challenge of a particular photographic task or not. **Anyone who is ready to start charging a fee for their photographic services should already be capable of answering that question for themself.**

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your personal photography knowledge. The [EOS 1100D](http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/142/Canon_EOS_1100D) is a perfectly capable camera however is considered as a 'amateur / beginner' model, rather than a model that is used in a professional environment.

*"The best camera is the one with you"*, though for a studio, I would recommend a Full-Frame model, possibly the [EOS 6D](http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/154/Canon_EOS_6D_) - You can see the specifications on my site

Comment: I understand, I think I have ? "You can see the specifications on my site"

Answer (score 0):

Studio work is mostly about lighting and lenses.. the camera stuck to the back of that lens is one of the least important things.  The difference between a good camera and a better camera in many situations now is how it deals with low light, but that's completely irrelevant in a studio situation where you bring your own.

At 12 megapixels it's a little on the light side compared to what's available, but it's not like successful studio shots just started happening when cameras evolved to 24 or 36!

Seems like you might need to understand "studio work".  Go to youtube and find videos on doing what you want to do and you'll soon find the lighting and lenses that people doing this feel are the minimum.

If you're more specific about what you want to shoot in this studio I can point you in the right direction of who I think is doing the best youtube work.